# WebBrowser Control C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi
Im using a webbrowser control to login to this url https://direct.gov.mb.ca/ppr/jsps/login/login.jsp
After entering correct username & password i will get redirected but to a non member page, (im still not logged in), I used fiddler and did the steps in the browser and successfully logged in , the only diff that i saw in the fidler between my program and just regular browser, is in the browser when i type the same URL , it would 2 cookies in the header which is very strange ,dont know where it gets those cookies, but with my program obviousely there is no cookie in the header, also after login with regular browser there are 5 cookies in the response but with my program there are only 2 cookies

I also want to mention that there is nothing wrong with my code , because i successfully logged in to other https  website and http websites , there is something unique about this site, how do i over come this issue, its been 3 days and i could not figure it out

**EDIT: Code**

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document; 
HtmlElementCollection elemsName = doc.All.GetElementsByName("userName"); 
int count = elemsName.Count; 
HtmlElement elmName = elemsName[0]; 
elmName.SetAttribute("value", "XXXXX"); 
HtmlElementCollection elemsPass = doc.All.GetElementsByName("password"); 
HtmlElement elmPass = elemsPass[0]; 
elmPass.SetAttribute("value", "XXXXX"); 
HtmlElementCollection elemsSubmit = doc.All.GetElementsByName("loginAction");
HtmlElement elmSubmit = elemsSubmit[0]; 
elmSubmit.InvokeMember("click");
```

But as i said the code works for other sites like facebook.com

Comment: When you get the request back from the first request (the login) there should be cookies which you need to "attach" to each request to be seen as logged in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try to clean the cookies before you opened the page with "regular browser"? If yes, is the count of cookies still the same?
2. Are user agents same in webbrowser and regular browser?
   If not, you can try to set them with:

   ```
   [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
   private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer,
   int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
   const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;

   private const string UserAgent = "Your User Agent";

   UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, UserAgent, UserAgent.Length, 0);
   ```
3. Have you checked the POST Body (TextView) for https://direct.gov.mb.ca/ppr/actions/loginDispatcher? Are they same?